# Copy Constructors Conflicting?

Tags: java

I have this snippet of my larger code;

```
    public PizzaOrder(PizzaOrder PizzaOrderCopy)
    {
        this.pizza1 = PizzaOrderCopy.pizza1;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PizzaOrder pizzorder = new PizzaOrder();

        pizzorder.setNumPizza(1);
        pizzorder.setPizza1("small",1,1,1);
        pizzorder.setPizza2("medium",3,6,4);
        pizzorder.setPizza3("large",2,4,4);
        pizzorder.getpizza1info();
        pizzorder.getpizza2info();
        pizzorder.getpizza3info();
        pizzorder.calcTotal();

    }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

I am making a copy constructor `PizzaOrderCopy` and making a copy of `PizzaOrders` object Pizza1. When I build this my code

```
PizzaOrdre pizzaorder = new PizzaOrder();
```

spazzes out

```
the constructor PizzaOrder is undefined
```

because it now wants a parameter.

How I see it (most probably wrong) is `PizzaOrder Copy` is a single copy and `Pizzaorder` is a single copy. so I wonder why they affect each other ? The only explanation I can think of is they are joined in some way.

Comment: You're not even *using* your copy constructor.

Comment: you are using your default constructor, in this case it doesn't exist because you defined your own constructor. Create a constructor with no arguments and this should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java compiler provides a default no parameter constructor when there is no constructor defined in the class. As you have defined a copy constructor in your class so compiler will not add the no-param constructor. And hence when you do this:

```
PizzaOrdre pizzaorder = new PizzaOrder();
```

you are calling the undefined no parameter constructor, which is causing the error. So simply add one no-param constructor in your PizzaOrdre class as metnioned here:

```
public PizzaOrder(){}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, its the first time I have needed to use more then one constructor :3

Answer (score 2):

You need to add constructor

```
public PizzaOrder()
{

}
```

and use your constructor like

```
PizzaOrder anotherPizzaOrder = new PizzaOrder();
...
PizzaOrder pizzorder = new PizzaOrder(anotherPizzaOrder);
```

Comment: Might want to explicitly state the problem. The reason is that the default ctor is only generated when no user defined ctors exist.

Answer (score 1):

The javac compiler only provides an implicit zero-parm constructor if you don't define any constructors.  So you need to define the zero-parm constructor as stated by Alex.